# How can i assure that data saves consistently in a flat file, before the route redirects in a node / express application?

Tags: node.js, express, filesystems, data-storage

I'm currently working on a Node / Express app that uses flat files for storage. The application uses a classic Model View Controller design pattern. The problem is that the routing in the controller seems to redirect before disk writing operations complete.

Originally, I tried to write my controllers as synchronous code, but even when I started using callback functions, this didn't seem to resolve the issue.

```js
// controllers/collection.js

const Collection = require('../models/collection');

exports.getIndex = (req, res) =>
    Collection.fetchAll(collections =>
        res.render('collection/index', { collections }))

exports.postAddCollection = (req, res) => 
    new Collection(null, req.body.collectionName).save(() => res.redirect('/'))


exports.postDeleteCollection = (req, res) => 
    Collection.delete(req.body.collectionId, () => res.redirect('/'))

// models/collection.js

const {
    setFileLocation,
    readDataFile,
    writeDataFile,
} = require('../utils/file-operations');

const uuid = require('uuid/v4');

const dataFile = setFileLocation('collections.json');

module.exports = class Collection {
    constructor(id, name) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    save(callBack) {
    readDataFile(dataFile, collections => {
        if (this.id) {
            const collectionIndex = collections.findIndex(
                collection => collection.id === this.id);
            const newCollections = [...collections];
            newCollections[collectionIndex] = this;
            writeDataFile(dataFile, newCollections, callBack);
        } else {
            this.id = uuid();
            collections.push(this);
            writeDataFile(dataFile, collections, callBack);
        }
    });
    }

    static fetchAll(callBack) {
        readDataFile(dataFile, callBack);
    }

    static delete(id, callBack) {
        readDataFile(dataFile, collections => {
            const newCollection = collections.filter(
            collection => collection.id !== id);
            writeDataFile(dataFile, newCollection, callBack);
        });
    }
};

// utils/file-operations.js
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

exports.setFileLocation = fileName =>
    path.join(path.dirname(process.mainModule.filename), 'data', fileName);

exports.readDataFile = (file, callBack) =>
    fs.readFile(file, (err, content) =>
        err ? callBack([]) : callBack(JSON.parse(content)),
    );

exports.writeDataFile = (file, data, callBack) =>
    fs.writeFile(file, JSON.stringify(data), err =>
        err ? console.log(err) : callBack(),
    );
```

Ideally, I'd like the disk operations to complete before the response redirect takes place, however at best, this only occurs about half the time. Most of the time the application quietly fails. Any suggestions on how to accomplish this? Thank you for your time.

Comment: Your `readDataFile()` and `writeDataFile()` never call the callback if there's an error.  That's clearly wrong.  You have no way of communicating back an error and any code waiting for completion will never see a completion callback if there's an error.  The usual convention is to call `callback(err)` or `callback(null)` if no error and then the caller can check for  an error.

Answer (score 0):

in writeDataFile, Try to do a

`err ? callback(err) : callBack()`

then catch it here:

```
new Collection(null, req.body.collectionName).save((err) => { 
    if(err)
       console.error(err);
    else 
       res.redirect('/')
})
```

Comment: Doing a `throw` from a regular asynchronous callback is useless as nobody can catch it.  Also, their `.save()` method does not currently communicate back errors (as my comment to the OP explains).

Comment: Thank you @jfriend00. I found out that the issue I was experiencing was not due to my codebase, but from a commonly used tool called nodemon. However, you did in fact bring up a very good point as far as the error handling was concerned. I will be revising my code as per your suggestion sometime this morning. Thank you very much for you time.